# generator versus nested for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, generator-expression

I have two methods to sum numbers found in a text file.  The first one works and the second one does not.  Can anyone explain what is wrong with the second one?.

Input text file:

```
The quick brown 123
fox 456 jumped over
the 789 lazy dog.
```

Method #1:

```
total = 0
for line in open(fn):
    numbers = (int(block) for block in line.split() if block.isdigit())
    total += sum(numbers)
print('total: ', total)
```

This gives the correct answer 1368 (= 123 + 456 + 789).

Method #2:

```
numbers = (int(block) for block in line.split() for line in open(fn) if block.isdigit())
total = sum(numbers)
print('total: ', total)
```

This produces the error:

```
NameError: name 'line' is not defined
```

I'm playing around with generators so the question is really about why the generator in method #2 is no good.  I don't need suggestions on *other* ways to add up numbers in a text file.  I would like to know if there is a generator-only solution without a standard for loop.  Thank you.

Comment: Place `for block in line.split() ` after the `for line in open(fn)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reversed the order of your loops. Generator expressions (like all Python comprehension syntax variants) list loops from *left to right* in *block nesting order*.

This works:

```
numbers = (int(block) for line in open(fn) for block in line.split() if block.isdigit())
```

because it matches the nesting order of the normal `for` loops (with only the per-iteration expression at the front):

```
numbers = (int(block)
    for line in open(fn)
        for block in line.split()
            if block.isdigit())
```

Your code tried to access `line.split()` before the `for line in open(fn)` loop could execute and set `line`.

See the [expressions reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries):

> The comprehension consists of a single expression followed by at least one `for` clause and zero or more `for` or `if` clauses. In this case, the elements of the new container are those that would be produced by considering each of the `for` or `if` clauses a block, **nesting from left to right**, and evaluating the expression to produce an element each time the innermost block is reached.

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks.  It makes sense now.